# How to set custom module as default in orchard cms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I made a custom module in orchard CMS.I want this custom module as startup module when i run my site but orchard always makes home page as start up.how can i make my custom module as Startup in orchard.My module is simple Mvc application using Entity frame work as db .I am pretty new to Orchard i am learning it.Any Help would be appriciated Thanks Advance

Comment: There are lots of different types of modules in Orchard and different ways to make them. It would help if you were more specific about what your module does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to steal the home route, you will have to write your own route, and give it high priority. Removing the alias for the current home page will also help.

Comment: Where I have to set priority in which class or method.you can tell me about specific file or component where I have to set my priority

Comment: The class where you define your route. Don't ignore the second part of my answer. There must not be an alias to /.

Answer (score 0):

If your module contains a content type and that content type has an autoroute part then there will be a checkbox in the edit content admin page that says 'Set to homepage'.

You can create lots of different types of modules in Orchard and not all of them contain content types. You can add an autoroute part to a content type that doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true to say "set a module as start up".a module is not an stand alone mvc application, but it is a way of extending existing functionalities.
you can create a `ContentType` inside your module and orchard will provide the dashboard user with creating of new instance of your type.then user can set this instance as home page content. 
to write your own `ContentType` check [here](http://patrickyong.net/2010/07/26/orchard-content-type/).